# how do you switch columns and rows in a gridview

Tags: gridview

Not looking to use listview or datalist. But I am trying to figure out how to switch my columns and rows.

for example my columns are projectname, projectaddress, etc. Id like these displayed as rows instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can flip your dataset before you load it into the gridview.

```
private void BindData()
{
    // Fill a dataTable with results

    // Add the dataTable to a DataSet
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    // Flip your dataSet
    DataSet new_ds = FlipDataSet(ds);
    new_ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Delete();

    DataView my_DataView = new_ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    gridView.DataSource = my_DataView;
    gridView.DataBind();
}

public DataSet FlipDataSet(DataSet my_DataSet)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    foreach(DataTable dt in my_DataSet.Tables)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        for(int i=0; i<=dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }

        DataRow r;

        for(int k=0; k<dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            r = table.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();

            for(int j=1; j<=dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                r[j] = dt.Rows[j-1][k];

            table.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(table);
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: My data is not preloaded into a dataset but rather put directly into the gridview from a sqldatasource see below:

Comment: @user1281748 You cannot flip the source using the SQLDataSource or Gridview settings as far as I know. You can convert the SQLDataSource's results to a DataSet and do what I posted above though. If you need an example of how to get an SQLDataSource to a dataTable check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532937/asp-net-c-sharp-put-round-sqldatasource-into-square-datatable-hole

Comment: Your Welcome! If the answer was exactly what you need dont forget to accept it. Also since this is your first time asking a question here you may want to check out the faq. Welcome to StackOverflow! http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: i put   /* create dataview from sql data source */
            DataView dv = (DataView)gvDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
           /* convert dataview to datatable */
            DataTable dt = dv.ToTable();

Comment: @user1281748 You can should be able to use the above since you have a dataTable now.

Comment: well it gave me an error when i put the BindData(); into my page load   if i take out the above lines it will display a blank form with no errors. if i take out BindData from page load i get my previous gridview

Comment: @user1281748You will have to change the gridview variable to match your variable name. If that does not fix your problem, I need to know more information about your error.

Comment: The gridview variable on the asp side is <asp:GridView ID="GridView1">  Which matches the Gridview1.DataBind(); in the BindData function. So it should work right? The <asp:GridView does contain a parameter from another sql datasource and also has bound datafields although im not sure that would change anything <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  DataSourceID="gvDataSource"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333" GridLines="None">
  <Columns><asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />

Comment: @user1281748 First of all the variable is gridView not GridView1 so that would cause an issue. Also the BoundDataFields will also be an issue because the values will not be columns anymore, but rather rows.